# How U-Boot passes parameters to MIPS Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, mips, u-boot

If we use **PowerPC CPU** with **U-Boot** then we may pass a lot of board-specific parameters to **Linux kernel** using **DTB** as described [here](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/LinuxFDTBlob).

**QUESTIONS:**

What is the preferred way to pass board-specific parameters to Linux kernel if we have **MIPS CPU** and **U-Boot**?

Can we pass all the necessary arguments (cash size, bus/cpu frequencies, flash parameters) using kernel arguments?

Comment: Have you looked at the U-Boot source code (e.g. arch/mips/lib/bootm.c)?

Comment: Seems that only kernel arguments are passed to kernel, nothing more...